# How to limit Django REST API to only ONE user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm coding a REST API with Django and I need to make some URLs limited to the only use of it's creator. I'm actually using an authentication token but in fact anyone with a token can use my API so I need to limit some functionalities to specific users.

An example would be like that:

```
Jonh Doe Token: roh2938rhe63eh0832yey3289
public --> domain.com/api/bobby/public/
public --> domain.com/api/jonhdoe/public/
private --> domain.com/api/jonhdoe/private/
```

And somehow only Jonh Doe should have access to that private URL even though the returned data is the same as usual, but just private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every user should have their unique authentication token. The way to allow access to certain users is by creating permissions. Permissions in Django are used to validate if user is authorised to perform certain actions.
Django way of creating permissions is to create `permissions.py` file inside relevant application folder and within that file you should write permission class that inherits `permissions.BasePermission` class and overrides `has_permission` method which returns `True` if user should have the permission or `False` otherwise. After doing that you simply add your permission class to the list of `permission_classes`.

**permissions.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsPrivateAllowed(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allow access to request owner
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # return True if allowed else False
        # 'username' is the request url kwarg eg. bobby, jonhdoe
        return view.kwargs.get('username', '') == request.user.username
```

We've created `IsPrivateAllowed` permission. For your example you should check if request token is compatible to the name argument in the url. Now import it and add it to the list of permissions of the class based view:

```
. . .
from .permissions import IsPrivateAllowed

class PrivateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsPrivateAllowed]
    . . .
```

What happens here is when user triggers an API call Django will first check if user meets all permissions from the list and if so - user will have access to a specific API call.